I would like some help regarding an async between a compose navigation and a ViewModel update
I'm quite new to android kotlin and i have a little problem regarding my login. When i press the login button i immediately get directed to the home screen but before the ViewModel can be updated so i get redirected back to the login screen resulting in me needing to press the login button twice to log on.
//Login Screen
@Composable
fun LogInScreen(
    onNavigateToHomeGraph: () -> Unit
) {
    val loginViewModel = koinViewModel<HasLoggedInViewModel>()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                successLogin(loginViewModel)
                returnToHome(onNavigateToHomeGraph)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp / 2)
                .align(Alignment.End)
        ) {
            Text(
                "Accedi"
            )
        }
    }
}

private fun successLogin(loggedInViewModel: HasLoggedInViewModel) {
    loggedInViewModel.changeLoginState(Login.Logged)
}

private fun returnToHome(onNavigateToHomeGraph: () -> Unit) {
    onNavigateToHomeGraph()
}


//Login.kt
enum class Login { Logged, NotLogged }

//HasLoggedInViewModel
data class LogState(val state: Login)

class HasLoggedInViewModel(
    private val repository: LogInStateRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val statelogin = repository.state.map { LogState(it) }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        initialValue = LogState(Login.NotLogged)
    )

    fun changeLoginState(state: Login) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.setLogin(state)
    }
}

//Repository
class LogInStateRepository(private val dataStoreLogin: DataStore<Preferences>) {
    companion object {
        private val LOG_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("login")
    }

    val state = dataStoreLogin.data
        .map { preferences ->
            try {
                Login.valueOf(preferences[LOG_KEY] ?: "NotLogged")
            } catch (_: Exception) {
                Login.NotLogged
            }
        }

    suspend fun setLogin(state: Login) =
        dataStoreLogin.edit { it[LOG_KEY] = state.toString() }
}

Basically i'm trying to have the navigation to the home screen wait for the viewmodel update, i tried using async/await and suspend with coroutines but suspend didn't seem to work since it's considered superflous on the successLogin() or returnToHome() functions also it would crash my app but that may be a wrong implementation on my part.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer.

The goal is to remain at the LogInScreen Composable until it is verified that the login was successful. You can try to achieve this by adding another state to your enum:
enum class Login { Logged, NotLogged, Loading }

Now, observe the statelogin StateFlow from your ViewModel in your Composable:
val loginState by loginViewModel.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

To use collectAsStateWithLifecycle, you need to add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2"

Now, depending on the state of the variable, you can do different things:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    when(loginState.state) {
        Login.NotLogged -> {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    successLogin(loginViewModel)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp / 2)
                    .align(Alignment.End)
            ) {
                Text("Accedi")
            }
        }
        Login.Logged -> {
            returnToHome(onNavigateToHomeGraph)
        }
        Login.Loading -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}

Also note that you need to implement some logic in your repository to actually verify the login credentials. So you will have to change this call
loggedInViewModel.changeLoginState(Login.Logged)

to something like
loggedInViewModel.tryLogin("myUsername", "myPassword")

and then validate the login credentials in your repository accordingly. As soon as the login button is pressed, you can set the state to Loading. Then, verify the credentials and set the state to either Logged or NotLogged depending on whether the credentials were valid:
suspend fun setLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    dataStoreLogin.edit { it[LOG_KEY] = Login.Loading }
    
    // check the credentials...
    
    if(validCredentials) {
        dataStoreLogin.edit { it[LOG_KEY] = Login.Logged}
    } else {
        dataStoreLogin.edit { it[LOG_KEY] = Login.NotLogged }
    } 
}


Thanks for the quick responce but i have a few question if you don't mind, i should have put this in the request but i actully use this method in the homeScreen as well (if the viewmodel is Logged i display the home contents otherwise i get redirected to login screen) so i need the default to be NotLogged but how do i handle the Loading state then? since my problem is the fact that the viewmodel update happens too late so i would need to delay the navigation or maybe i'm missing something with this method?

Wait i think i got it do i need to change the Login.valueOf(preferences[LOG_KEY] ?: "NotLogged") in the repository to Login.valueOf(preferences[LOG_KEY] ?: "Loading") ?

Yes, I edited my post, sorry, my answer was incomplete before. I hope it is clear now.

OK thanks a ton you saved me

@nm16pc I am happy to help! If this answer resolved your question, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of my answer.
